# Index Out of bounds exception on android studio

Tags: android, mysql, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this error:

```
D/Final Error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

With this code:

```
public class Display_data extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> Displist = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView no_name;
String db_Name;
TextView namer;
TextView Starter;
TextView Ender;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        no_name = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Disp_list);
        String message = bundle.getString("package");
        String parameter;
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(message, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor header;
        namer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.T1);
        try {
            header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'", null);
            String temp = header.getString((header.getColumnIndex("Train_name")));
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "blahhh:"+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Sucess!","temp:"+temp);
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Gotcha:"+temp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            namer.setText("Train Name: " + temp);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Final Error",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    db_Name=message.substring(0,(message.length()-3));
    try{
        Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select Stops From "+db_Name, null);
        while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
            String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Stops"));
            if(Displist.contains(name)) {

            }
            else {
                Displist.add(name);
                //Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Added :"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
        data_fetch.close();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Yeah"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Damn Why",e.toString());

    }
    try {

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Displist);
        no_name.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Display data error ",e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Listview Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Googling the error i found out that it could be due to the value not being present in the `database`

This is the code for the creation and insertion into the `database`:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list ("
                + "Train_name VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_no VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_start VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_end VARCHAR,"
                + "Seats_Available VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO Train_list (Train_name, Train_no, Train_start, Train_end, Seats_Available) VALUES('"+str_Train_name + "',' " +str_Train_no + "', '" +str_Train_start+"','" +str_Train_end+"',' " +str_Train_seats +"');";
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "train no:"+str_Train_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Sorry Not Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error experienced",e.toString());
        }
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        name1=str_Train_no+".db";
        SQLiteDatabase traindb = openOrCreateDatabase(name1, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
        sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+str_Train_no+"("
                +"Stops VARCHAR);";
        traindb.execSQL(sql);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Table "+str_Train_no+" verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "An Error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And i have verified that the value that I'm trying to retrieve indeed does exist in the database. As the insertion code for the `database` 'Train_list' did not generate any `exceptions`.

Any idea whats going on Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you insert data using this query db.execSQL(sql);
instead get the long value returned from execSQL(sql) to check whether the record is inserted or not. like this
long id = db.execSQL(sql);
Log.d(TAG,"Record Inserted " + id); it id is 1 then record is inserted if it is zero then record is not inserted

Comment: @DemoMail When i did that i got an error that said incompatible  types Required : long Found :void